# Drupal httpswww

Tags: php, https, drupal-8

How to fix this error?

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\httpswww\EventSubscriber\HttpsWwwRedirectSubscriber::redirect() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent given in Drupal\httpswww\EventSubscriber\HttpsWwwRedirectSubscriber->redirect() (line 54 of modules\httpswww\src\EventSubscriber\HttpsWwwRedirectSubscriber

I have installed this module on my website now i can't access the front end edit, or uninstall the module

Comment: What version of Drupal 8 are you running? What PHP version? Have you tried uninstalling with Drush and/or composer ([Uninstalling Modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/extending-drupal/uninstalling-modules))? You can disable the module by adding `$config['httpswww.settings']['enabled'] = FALSE;` to your `settings.php` file.